# How to split a cell in table in Word 2010 so it can display 2 elements as a table header?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to split or divide one cell so it can hold 2 text values divided. Something like:
[image]

Comment: Add variant 2, nay be it good).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left side set Subscpipt, several space , right side set Superscript font properties.

[image: Subscpipt Superscript font]

Variant 2:

1. Split left Cell.

[image: Split Cell]

2. Hide the central line between the left two cells.
3. Insert -> Shapes -> Line; Draw a line from corner to corner.

[image: diag line Draw Table]

Answer (score 4):

In the top left cell create 2x2 table with invisible borders. Then in this nested table add diagonal border to top left and bottom right cells:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Here it looks nice, but in real life it sometimes could be very ugly. But, this is the most reliable way from my point of view. You can write the text of any length and use any font size. Also, shapes (as suggested in original answer) are sometimes misaligned when you change the paper size - I don't use them in any of my documents.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Okay, 2 reasons why the accepted answer is unperfected, and why I post mine.

1. You can't draw a line which can split cell perfectly, like this:
   the left side is my solution, the right side is the accepted one. You can draw it in Word, I can't draw the line better.
   [image]
2. You need to modify line again if you change the width of the cell.

Original screenshot of the comments:

[image]

---

I found an easy way to do this. Click the `Draw Table` button, and your mouse become a pencil, then draw a line to split the cell. Voila.

[image]

Comment: So you select the cell you want to divide, then click on Insert Table and Draw Table, and then use the mouse on the original cell?  And it figures out that you want to split the cell diagonally as long as you mouse from close to one corner to close top the other?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you. I'd keep the screenshot, this the reason why I have to edit the answer for many times. I agree that it's silly to explain why your answer should not be deleted to prevent it from being deleted, but I have no choice. :)

Comment: Is my understanding right about how you use the tool (as opposed to doing something on the grid within the tool, for example)? If so, it wouldn't hurt to add that info to the answer since that key piece is ambiguous. BTW, answers are for the ages, and for other readers who find this because of a similar question. Nobody will ever know or care how many times the answer was edited, or why. The comment history about the process is really irrelevant and a distraction when someone finds the thread and sees a great answer.   The best answers on SU have ridiculous numbers of edits to perfect them.